# PyroCMS errors on Production server with Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-objec

Tags: codeigniter, pyrocms

I have a **PyroCMS 2.1.5** site that works perfectly on my dev and staging servers and have now uploaded it to the planned production server and get this error:
Call to a member function `num_rows()` on a non-object in `/home/lele1063/public_html/system/codeigniter/database/DB_driver.php` on line 755

I have reloaded the /system files and the database but no luck. Am at my wits end on this one.
Production server is running PHP 5.3.27, not sure on MySQL version tho.

Comment: do you have any custom modules? or models?

Comment: check your database settings for the production environment (those in $db[PYRO_PRODUCTION]). I'm pretty sure this non-sense error message occurs if PyroCMS couldn't make a connection to your db.

Comment: @Jahandideh - Thanks for your coment - No custom modules or models

Comment: @mgrueter - Thanks Marco for that excellent suggestion. For a moment I felt like a total dork. But in this case I have the .htaccess and db config file as well as the usrname pw and dbname all correct. I also had in mind that if PyroCMS cannot make a db connection it would display a Pyro error message.

Comment: **SOLVED** - It was indeed due to no established db connection. Something to watch out for on c-Panel!! - My first time with NetRegistry's hosting and db setup!!